# order columns by name when using SchemaExport

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

i have a legacy db structure like

```
table t1
(
  c0 bigint, // pk
  c10 bigint,  // deleted flag
)

table t2
(
  c0 bigint, // pk
  c1 bigint, // fk to t1.c0
  c10 bigint,  // deleted flag
)
```

and classes

```
class Entity
{
    public virtual long Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual long Property { get; set; }
}

class Parent : Entity
{
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Childs { get; private set; }
}

class Child : Entity { }
```

After mapping it with MappingByCode or FNH, SchemaExport will create the columns in the wrong order.

```
table t2
(
  c0 bigint, // pk
  c10 bool,  // deleted flag
  c1 bigint, // fk to t1.c0
)
```

How can i make sure the columns are created in ascending order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after digging through the source code i came up with this

```
configuration.BeforeBindMapping += (sender, e) =>
{
    // change to foreach if more than one classmapping per file
    var c = e.Mapping.RootClasses[0];
    c.Items = 
        // sort everything with a column (simple property, reference, ...)
        c.Items.OfType<IColumnsMapping>().OrderBy(cm => cm.Columns.First().name)
        // concat everything that has no column (collection, formula, ...)
        .Concat(c.Items.Where(o => !(o is IColumnsMapping))).ToArray();
};
```